Error relacionado con la configuracion de la BBDD en hibernate/spring boot
¿Cómo puedo entender y solucionar el error:
"Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata" 

en una aplicación Spring Boot/Hibernate que no me permite arrancar?

Puedes mostrar tu archivo application.properties o application.yml

Debes agregar en tu configuración (application.properties o application.yml):

spring.datasource.url con la URL de la BBDD.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect si usas un dialecto personalizado.

